# Which angle should we take when asked the angle between vector A and vector B?

Tags: vectors, angle

Suppose a vector is like this in $x$-$y$ plane.

[image: Vector image]

Now suppose a question is asked what is the angle betweeen vector $B$ and $A$. What will be the answer? Is it $\theta$ or $360-\theta$ ? I am asking this question because I have heard two contradictory rules for this.

**First rule:** It should be taken in anti-clockwise direction.

**Second rule:** The smaller angle should be taken.

Comment: Look up "the right-hand rule."

Comment: Um could you please elaborate? I want to know which angle to take for calculations.

Comment: Um... Did you look up "the right-hand rule" as I recommended?  It states *precisely* which angle to use.  Over and out.

Comment: Yes I have looked it up. But which site are you mentioning?

Comment: See the Definition section of the Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product

Comment: There are many thousands of such sites, all of which explain this basic notion clearly.  Here's youtube:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zGyfiOqiR4s

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I have changed the question to a more general one. I mean I was just giving cross product as an example. Now I have changed the question to without any examples as I generally want to know which angle is considered the angle between the two vectors.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Question on the angle between two vectors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4375191/question-on-the-angle-between-two-vectors)

Comment: Angles must be measured anticlockwise only if the direction matters.

Comment: @ryang so you are telling that angle between vector $B$ and $A$ is $360 - \theta$ ?

Comment: @ryang I read the answer. I want to make sure if what I understood from that answer is right or not.

Answer (score 1):

1. Notice that the big angle plus the small angle is $2\pi$ radians and:
   $$
   sin(2\pi-x)=-sin(x)
   $$
2. Notice that the vector that is the cross-product of $\overrightarrow{A}$ and $\overrightarrow{B}$ is perpendicular to both $\overrightarrow{A}$ and $\overrightarrow{B}$. If you see, [right-hand-rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-hand_rule), it is clear that the answer depends  on whether you are looking for $\overrightarrow{A} \ X\ \overrightarrow{B}$ or $\overrightarrow{B} \ X\ \overrightarrow{A}$
3. Notice that by property of cross product:
   $$
   \overrightarrow{A} \ X\ \overrightarrow{B}=-(\overrightarrow{B} \ X\ \overrightarrow{A})
   $$

Hence the answer to your question depends:

**If you are looking for $\overrightarrow{A} \ X\ \overrightarrow{B}$ then, use the angle that goes counter-clockwise from $\overrightarrow{A}$ to $\overrightarrow{B}$.
If you are looking for $\overrightarrow{B} \ X\ \overrightarrow{A}$ then, use the angle that goes counterclockwise from $\overrightarrow{B}$ to $\overrightarrow{A}$.**

Edit: as mentioned by many, there are plenty of resources that explained this better, if you just type "right-hand-rule" on google

Comment: I have changed the question to a more general one. I mean I was just giving cross product as an example. Now I have changed the question to without any examples as I generally want to know which angle is considered the angle between the two vectors.

Comment: For this changed question, @Valoruz, you should look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1835007/is-the-angle-between-a-and-b-is-equal-to-the-angle-between-b-and-a?rq=1)

Comment: So the conclusion is that the angle between vector $B$ and $A$ is $\theta$ and not $360 - \theta$?